# Name for a certain class of groups that contains all the abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, terminology

I cam across this type of groups. Is there a name for groups that satisfy this condition:
$$\forall x,y\in G[xyx^{-1}\in \langle y\rangle]$$
As mentioned in the title, it is easy to see that all the abelian groups satisfy this condition.

Thank you

Comment: Some MathJax advice:

`<` and `>` mean "less than" and "greater than", and produce spacing correct for that meaning only; to make angle brackets, use `\langle` and `\rangle`.

Comment: @ZevChonoles OK. I will edit it.

Comment: So all subgroups are normal. I would call such groups perfectly normal or completely normal, to borrow from topology.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes all subgroups are all normal. Is perfectly normal used for groups ?

Comment: I don't think so. But the condition can be phrased as "all subgroups are normal", so I thought if they don't already have a name, why not use one of the more esoteric "XYly normal" variants.

Comment: @DanielFischer They are called dedekind groups. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_group

Comment: Pity, in a way. But if it honours Dedekind, I cannot be sad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $G$ is a group such that for all $x,y \in G$, $xyx^{-1} \in \langle y \rangle$, then every cyclic subgroup is normal. Conversely if every cyclic subgroup is normal, then $G$ satisfies the condition.

More commonly this is expressed as every subgroup is normal: if every cyclic subgroup is normal, and $H \leq G$ is any subgroup, then $H$ is the product of the cyclic subgroups $\langle y \rangle$ for $y \in H$, so $H$ too is normal. The converse is clear.

A group in which every subgroup is normal is called a [Dedekind group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_group). A non-abelian Dedekind group is of the form $Q_8 \times P \times V$ where $P$ is a periodic abelian group with no elements of even order and $V$ is an abelian group all of whose elements have order dividing 2. These were classified by Dedekind (1897) in the finite case and Baer (1933) in general. A modern proof is theorem 5.3.7 on page 139 of Robinson (1982).

- Dedekind, R.; 
  “Ueber Gruppen, deren sämmtliche Theiler Normaltheiler sind.”
  Math. Ann. 48 (1897), no. 4, 548–561.
  MR[1510943](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1510943)
  JFM[28.0129.03](http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zmath/en/search/?q=an:28.0129.03)
  DOI:[10.1007/BF01447922](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01447922)
- Baer, R.
  “Situation der Untergruppen und Struktur der Gruppe.”
  [J] Sitzungsberichte Heidelberg (1933), Nr. 2, 12-17 (1933).
  JFM[59.0143.02](http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zmath/en/search/?q=an:59.0143.02)
- Robinson, Derek J. S.
  “A course in the theory of groups.”
  Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 80.
  Springer-Verlag, New York, 1982. xviii+481 pp.
  ISBN: 0-387-90600-2
  MR[648604](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=648604)
  DOI:[10.1007/978-1-4684-0128-8](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4684-0128-8)
  DOI:[10.1007/978-1-4419-8594-1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4419-8594-1)